# Changing Browser Configuration on LinkClick

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox, mozilla

on my website I want to give one the ability to change his Javascript-Settings with one buttonclick.

For Example:

MySite detects: Javascript disabled -> Refering to an error-site -> Errorsite displays a tutorial on how to change javascript and offers the possibility to click on a button ( button is generated, depending on which browser the user uses ) -> If user clicks on the button, his javascript is enabled.

In Firefox the first thing comming into my mind was:

```
<a href="about:config"></a>
```

In Chrome:

```
<a href="chrome://settings"></a>
```

In Opera:

```
<a href="opera://config"></a>
<a href="opera://flags"></a> <!-- For experimental Javascript -->
```

Now im searching for an solution to directly changing the settings for javascript. 
Those links above should only open the settings-sites for those browsers.

Maybe there's something like that:

```
<a href="about:config?javascript.enabled=true"></a>
```

Greetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your website cannot change user preferences. Random websites changing all kinds of (sensitive) preferences, even if the user has to click first, would be a security, privacy and support nightmare.

Consider some troll convincing tech-illiterate users to click on a link that will disable Javascript or Cookies: user is left with what appears to be a broken user... Or a troll changing proxy/SSL settings around, so he'd be able to snoop on users...